# php product browser

Tags: php, database, oscommerce, catalog

I was wondering if anyone knows of a good script to manage a catalog of products. Just need basic stuff, like being able to browse by category and or tags and search. Without many extras, as I'd like to have it working inside a CMS.

softpedia has a few scripts, but I'm also considering creating it from scratch. Ideal would be something in between that allows a bit of customization and control of layout, but takes care of the backend. So adding editing and managing items should be simple.

any ideas?

--- edit ---

has anyone worked with http://www.oscommerce.com and can shed some light?

Comment: This could be something you could implement by yourself for the experience especially it being basic. Depending on your level of experience and how greatly into detail you would like the script to be, you can add more implementations down the road. The decision is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CubeCart](http://www.cubecart.com/) is quite simplistic and easy to use, there's also [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/) and [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) if your looking for a more advanced ecommerce system.

Answer (score 1):

[ZenCart](http://www.zen-cart.com/) is a popular solution, and free.  Of course any (good) product listing app is going to be a shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

virtuemart may work out for you as well.. you can add it on top of joomla .. that way you would have a CMS to create and change the custom pages as well.. the other solutions are good too but they are more cart oriented.